# s3 bucket images can access via website only

Tags: amazon-s3

I am new to S3 , i created a bucket there and uploaded the images.

I want to access that images via my website only. onlybody able to access that bucket.

Please tell me how we can proceed on the same ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389394/how-do-i-download-a-file-with-php-and-the-amazon-s3-sdk

Comment: Very similar to: [AWS S3 implementation for serving private files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47237134/174777)

Comment: What do you mean by "via my website only"? Do you mean only if your website is the *Referrer*, or does access require the users to authenticate themselves and your application will then determine exactly which files they are allowed to access? (Feel free to Edit your question to add more details.)

Comment: i have domain name example.com . i want to server these images files using image tag